# Swift doesn't generate unused variable warning

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

In Objective-C, the following code generates **Unused variable** warning:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger unusedVariable;
}
```

But in Swift, the following same code does not generate the warning:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var unusedVariable: Int
}
```

Xcode version is 6.0.1.
Build Settings > Unused Variables is YES in Swift project.

Is this happening only to me?
How to make Swift or Xcode generate Unused variable warning in Swift?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Chris Lattner's](http://devforums.apple.com/message/1048463#1048463) post on the Apple Developer Forums, this is still a bug:

> It's a known issue, we have a radar for it, thanks!
>
> -Chris

**Update**: Not only does Swift now have unused variable warnings, it also is also yells at you when you use a `var` where a `let` would suffice.

Comment: @fabian789 I have not checked, but I don't remember seeing any unused car warnings in swift recently.

Comment: True. I thought maybe I was missing some setting, but I just checked my warnings and Unused Variables is on... So not in there yet I suppose.

Comment: Here is the bug report in swift.org: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2849